# application. Run

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Anyone know how to stop this code on button click? I have a code that returns a random value from a list every second. I recorded a macro button that runs on click but I cannot break the code without opening the debugger.

Here is what I have

```
Sub Calculate_range()
Range("D1").Calculate
Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 1, Now), "Calculate_range"
End Sub
```

```
'button 1
Sub Start()

    Application.Run "Book1.xlsm!Calculate_range"

End Sub

' I tried the below but it does not work

'button 2
```

```
Sub Stop()

    Application.Quit "Book1.xlsm!Calculate_range"

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to cancel the scheduled run using the exact time it was scheduled for.  See the linked duplicate post.